# Is it possible to create an Excel add in that is compatible with all versions of Excel from 2010 to 2016?

Tags: excel, office-addins, excel-addins

I have Visual Studio 2015 Community and I have the following options to create a new project. Will any of these projects create an Add-in that will work in all versions of Excel 2010 to 2016 (2007 if possible as well)? All I want to do is add a button to the ribbon and have it submit some data to a web service. Would be great if I could just write the Add-in once.

- Excel Add-in
- Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-in
- Excel 2010 VSTO Add-in

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: depends on what your going to be using that exists or doesnt exist in certain versions. But you only need to write 1 add-in,  just use  `application.version` to test what version is being used and add code appropriately for these issues,

Comment: Thanks, @StevenMartin. So which of the three options would you choose? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a no. The old Office versions (2007 / 2010) uses the COM extensions, which were more on the native side of things, the newer versions (2013 / 2016) uses the add-in model which is basically an iframe of your app loaded into the application allowing you to interact with the document.

Answer (score 0):

This is years after the question was asked, but the answer then, as now, is 'Yes'.

[Excel-DNA](https://excel-dna.net) is a free and open-source library that allows you to create .xll add-ins with .NET in Visual Studio. These add-ins can run in Excel '97 through Excel 2019 as well as the latest Office 365 versions (though only on Windows). You'd have separate .xll add-ins for 32-bit and 64-bit Excel, but the assembly compiled from you C#, VB.NET or F# project will be the same.